# I used the <script> tag for the JS and the <style> tag for the CSS but the JS doesn't seem to respond.

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used the `<script>` tag for the JS and the `<style>` tag for the CSS but the JS doesn't seem to respond. Please help.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/fXbyGKRF

Comment: where u included the jquery file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include jQuery file just after stylesheet. either locally or from Google CDN

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to include jquery file too in that html file

Comment: I used the <script> tag though. Isn't that what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: you have to include jquery file too to make them functions work

Comment: and use that file before them functions